# How to use a variable in an Sybase update statement

Tags: variables, sybase

This query is to prove a concept that I will eventually use to locate all columns with a specific value and then create a name/value pair for export to JSON. But I'm stuck.

I query the list of all columns from the sql table. I would then like to go through the columns in Table1 row by row and update the values using the variable to construct the query. For example as it reads through the list if Col4 = "Old text" then I would like to set the value of Col 4 = "New Text"

```
DECLARE @c varCHAR(100)
DECLARE ReadData CURSOR
FOR SELECT cname FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE creator = 'dbserver' AND tname = 'Table1' 
    DECLARE @RowCount INT

SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(cname) FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE creator = 'dbserver' AND tname = 'Table1')
OPEN ReadData

DECLARE @I INT // iterator

SET @I = 1 // initialize
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT ReadData INTO @c

INSERT INTO serverdb.Table2 (cname)VALUES(@c)// this works inserting all 100 columns in the cname column of Table 2

UPDATE serverdb.Table1 SET @c = 'New text' WHERE @c = 'Old text'// this fails with a syntax error. @c is not being interpreted for the query. Note: If I hard code the @c var (for testing)to a known column name, the query works as well

SET @I = @I  + 1
END;
```

Why won't the update statement recognize the variable? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you use varibale as mentioned below it is considered as a character string.

```
UPDATE serverdb.Table1 SET @c = 'New text' WHERE @c = 'Old text'
```

You need to create a dynamic query. use the execute method to execute your dynamic query

```
declare @sql varchar(999)
SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE serverdb.Table1 SET '+ @c + '= ''New text'' WHERE '+ @c+ ' = ''Old text'' '
execute(@sql)
```

Hope this helps